# Fresh EC2 instance pending Kernel Upgrade

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2

Just spin up an EC2 instance with Ubuntu, if it is a new fresh instance, isn't supposed the Kernel to be up to date?

After I run a `sudo apt update && sudo apt install <any-package>`, I receive the message below:

```
Package configuration

  ┌───────────────────────┤ Pending kernel upgrade ├───────────────────────┐
  │                                                                        │ 
  │ Newer kernel available                                                 │ 
  │                                                                        │ 
  │ The currently running kernel version is 5.15.0-1031-aws which is not   │ 
  │ the expected kernel version 5.19.0-1022-aws.                           │ 
  │                                                                        │ 
  │ Restarting the system to load the new kernel will not be handled       │ 
  │ automatically, so you should consider rebooting.                       │ 
  │                                                                        │ 
  │                                 <Ok>                                   │ 
  │                                                                        │ 
  └────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Is this normal? If not, how can I avoid it?

Comment: Had same issue spinning up from an Ubuntu AMI on EC2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please *read* the message. It explains things perfectly.

The headline is *Pending kernel upgrade*, which informs you that there's a newer kernel pending.

The last line informs you what do to apply this change:

> Restarting the system to load the new kernel will not be handled automatically, so you should consider rebooting.

And no, you are not guaranteed that images are perfectly up to date at all times. You should perform required upgrades after deploying.

Comment: I got this message, read it and figured "I probably just need to restart after a fresh install". So I did. However, now I am getting it again after doing an apt update. Is *that* normal? I think the question here isn't what the message says so much as what it really imposes. How often will my kernel become pending an upgrade and require restarting?

Comment: @AlexiTheodore kernel updates is normal. You don't have to reboot, but you won't get the benefits of you don't. Canonical offers a live patch service if you can't reboot.